# Having a hard time inheriting scope from parent in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I have the following two controllers, a parent and a child, and I need a value that is dynamically added to the parent scope passed on into the child scope. I really can't understand how the service injection works either. Here is my parent controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("myApp").controller("singleTopicController", ["RestFullResponse", "Restangular", "localStorageService", "$scope", "$window", "$stateParams", function(RestFullResponse, Restangular, localStorageService, $scope, $window, $stateParams){

  var topics = Restangular.one('topics', $stateParams.id);

  var Topics = topics.get({},{"Authorization" : localStorageService.get('***')}).then(function(topic){
    $scope.topic = topic;
    $scope.topic.id = topic.id;
    $window.document.title = 'Example | ' + $scope.topic.topic_title;

    console.log($scope.topic);
  });

}]);
```

And my child controller which needs the topic.id to work.

```
'use strict';

angular.module("myApp").controller("commentSingleController", ["RestFullResponse", "Restangular", "localStorageService", "$scope", "$state", "$stateParams", "$timeout", function(RestFullResponse, Restangular, localStorageService, $scope, $state, $stateParams, $timeout){

  $scope.topic = {};

  var oneTopic = Restangular.one('topics', $scope.topic.id);
      oneTopic.get({}, {"Authorization" : localStorageService.get('***')}).then(function(topic) {
        topic.getList('comments', {}, {"Authorization" : localStorageService.get('***')}).then(function(comments){
          $scope.comments = comments;
          console.log($scope.comments);
        });
      });

      $scope.isCollapsed = true;

      var comments = Restangular.all('comments');

      $scope.commentData = {
        //topic_id: $scope.parent.topic.id
      };

      $scope.postComment = function(mood) {
        $scope.commentData.mood = mood;
        comments.post($scope.commentData, {}, {"Authorization" : localStorageService.get('***')}).then(function(response){
          $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
            reload: true,
            inherit: false,
            notify: true
          });
        }, function(response){
          $scope.error = response.data.message;
        })
      };

}]);
```

If I add

```
console.dir($scope.$parent);
```

to the child controller, topic is obviously there.

[image]

But if I try

```
console.dir($scope.$parent.topic);
```

I get undefined.

I tried wrapping the Restangular.get() of the child controller in a watcher but that didn't do anything.

```
$scope.$watch('topic', function{
```

Restangular.one() ...})

Where am I going wrong here.

```
<div class="main-left-column">
  **<div ng-controller="singleTopicController">** //my main controller

      <div class="topic-full">
        <div class="topic-left">
          <div class="topic-left-inner">
            <a ui-sref="main.topic({id: topic.id})"><h4>{{ topic.topic_title }}</h4></a>
            <hr>
            <img ng-src="{{ topic.image_url }}" class="img-responsive img-topic" tooltip="{{ topic.topic_title}}"/>
            <hr ng-if="topic.image_url">
            <p>{{ topic.topic_content }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="topic-right">
          **<div class="topic-right-inner" ng-controller="commentSingleController">** //child controller
            <img ng-src="{{ topic.profile_pic }}" width="60px" class="profile-pic"/>
            <div class="topic-data">
              <h4 class="topic-data">{{ topic.author_name }}</h4>
              <h5 class="topic-data">- posted on {{ topic.created_at }}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-count">
              <div class="comment-count-mood red" tooltip="Negative comments"><p>{{ topic.comments_angry }}</p></div>
              <div class="comment-count-mood yellow" tooltip="Neutral comments"><p>{{ topic.comments_sad }}</p></div>
              <div class="comment-count-mood green" tooltip="Positive comments"><p>{{ topic.comments_happy }}</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <hr>
            <p ng-if="comments.length == 0">No comments</p>
            <div class="line-through">
              <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
                <div class="comment-left">
                  <img ng-src="{{ comment.profile_pic }}" width="40px" class="comment-pic"/>
                  <div class="comment-mood" ng-class="{'red': comment.mood == 2, 'yellow': comment.mood == 1, 'green': comment.mood == 0}"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-right">
                  <h4 class="comment-data">{{ comment.author_name }}</h4>
                  <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <hr class="dotted" ng-if="!$last">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: Added HTML. Controller wrappers are in asterisks.

Comment: Where is your HTML? I don't see in your code how your controllers are related. Note: every controller gets his own `$scope`.

Comment: Added the HTML for context.

Comment: Preparing a fiddle with an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** will make it possible to identify the real problem instead of taking guesses...

Comment: BTW, the Angular wiki has a topic about **[Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)** which clears many things up (if someone is not familiar with the inner workings of JavaScript's prototypal inheritance). Most of the times, the issue is related to a misunderstanding of this concept.

Comment: Yeah I'm actually quite new to js in general so it's quite confusing. Sorry for the code as well. I'll try and set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your topic won't be created until your `.get` in your parent controller resolves, which is probably after the initialisation of the child controller.

If you remove the `$scope.topic = {}` from the child controller and add a `$watch` for `topic.id` you should be able to use the id in there.

Really you shouldn't need $scope.$parent as $scope should have everything the parent does unless it's been hidden by something in the child scope or there's an isolate scope in the way (there isn't in this case).

Comment: So would I wrap the entire contents of the child controller in a watch then?

Comment: Alright I got it working wrapped in $scope.watch('topic', function(topic){ ... }); I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way though.

Comment: @PavelRogala I think the cleaner way would be to put the child code into a directive and use an explicit binding.